# In Xcode, how to include resources with folder structure?

Tags: xcode, xcode13, xcode-build-settings

In Xcode, I created some HTML help files and put them in a folder, like this:

[image]

But when Xcode builds the final app package, it flattens the folder structure.

```
ls ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources
...     help.css    help.en.html
```

And the following code crashes, because it expected a subdirectory:

```swift
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "help.en", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "Help")!
```

Is there a way to make it copy the directory structure to the output? I will have more files and I don't want to think about name clashes.